# JPA: add should not fail if one of the rows cant be added

Tags: hibernate, jpa, batch-file, jpa-2.0

I use JPA + Hibernate.

I have 2 entities (Parent, Child) with OneToMany connection between them. I add a list of children to the parent like this:

```
parent.setChildrent(childrenSet);
getEntityManager().merge(parent);
```

If one of the children entities contains invalid values (for example, too long string), its insert fails, and the whole transaction fails.

Is there a way to ignore/log the error, and continue the merge for the rest of children?

I understand that I can add children one-by-one, but is there a better solution?

thank you.

Comment: Why would you just want to ignore a critical error like that? I've never encountered a requirement that would want the application to behave in this manner. Data validation is a primary concern of any data-related application.

Comment: I don't want to fail the transaction, because this data is critical for user, and I prefer to save at least a part of it and present it to user. I want to log a failure, or maybe truncate a string if its too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If one of the children entities contains invalid values (for example, too long string),...

You shouldn´t handle problems like that by handle database errors.
Try to filter too long strings or invalid values in your application before you start a transaction to the database.

If there is a database error a rollback is performed and all changes performed while this transaction will be undone.

Best regards

Comment: I don't want to be aware of database structure (for these validations I need to know that child properties will be saved in varchar(255) columns).

Comment: sorry, but i think i didnt´t get your point.
You don´t know the database-structure for your application?

Comment: In JPA I declare a String field, Hibernate (or DBA) decide to create it as varchar(255), or varchar(511), or anything else. I don't want to be aware of this.
I do want to ignore such errors and save the valid children

Comment: Maybe there is a way to make such validations in JPA without hard-coding the table column type (varchar255)?

Comment: you shouldn´t let hibernate decide, which datatype in db is used. In fact only you as the coder know, how long values stored in that column might can be. You maybe use the "columnDefinition" or "length"(for String) attribute of Hibernate. [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/)

It´s definitly not the function of a JPA-Class to validate values.
You have to do that before the transaction is performed.